# "Cachinnare" significa ridere per beffa?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Ne vennero fuori caratteri melodrammaticamente spartiti fra il buono e il malvagio: di me ho detto, non c'era scena in cui non **cachinnassi** intento a qualche nuova vassallata, mordicchiando sadicamente dei fili di paglia o frustando le mie fidanzate con la cinghia;

Con queste parole, Gassman descrive il suo ruolo nel film *Riso amaro*. Non capisco il significato di "cachinnare" nel brano precedente. Questo verbo non appare nel vocabolario Treccani, ma si trova invece la definizione del termine "[cachinno](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cachinno/)":

> s. m. [dal lat. *cachinnus*], letter. – Scroscio di risa sguaiate, soprattutto per beffa: *«lo tuo riso sia sanza cachinno», cioè sanza schiamazzare come gallina* (Dante).

Si può dedurre che il senso di "cachinnare" è quello di ridere smodatamente facendo beffa di qualcosa?

Comment: Risa sguaiate sì, ma non devono per forza essere per beffa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il verbo "cachinnare" si trova sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI23/00198.jpg), in cui si spiega che ha il significato seguente:

> **Cachinnare**, 
>   intr.  Ridere  sguaiatamente  e smodatamente, per  lo  più  in  modo  beffardo  e  sarcastico,  mostrando  scherno  e derisione. 
>       *Imbriani*,  8-49:  «Ed  io»  rantolò  sibilando  «ed  io  ti  dò  d’impietrire con  gli  occhi, quanti ne  incontreranno lo sguardo». E si guardò intorno poi  sghignazzando  e  cachinnando,  fregandosi  le  mani  e  stropicciando­le,  come  chi  si  pregi  d’aver  fatta  una  bella  cosa  e  ne  aspetti  plauso  e congratulazioni dagli astanti. 
>      
>   = Voce dotta, lat. *cachinnāre*.

Quindi, l'ipotesi fatta nella domanda si è verificata.

Comment: Non so se può essere utile. Una veloce ricerca mi ha portato qui: https://sapere.virgilio.it/parole/vocabolario/cachinnare

Comment: Grazie, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, ma il problema è che non sappiamo qual è la fonte di quello che hai trovato.

Comment: La fonte è riportata sotto: "Tratto dalla voce CACHINNARE del Wikizionario
Rilasciato con licenza Creative Commons CC BY-SA"

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Wikizionario non è veramente una fonte e, cercando questo verbo lì, si trova: "Questo termine non è presente in nessuno dei vocabolari da me consultati, ovvero Garzanti, De Mauro, Devoto-Oli. Ne ho trovato traccia nei romanzi *Il pendolo di Focault* e *Il nome della rosa*, entrambi di Umberto Eco. Non so se si tratta di un suo neologismo, ma a mio avviso, data l'importanza dell'autore, è un lemma che merita di essere inserito". Quindi, sembra che la definizione sia stata inventata da non si sa chi.

Comment: Io personalmente non mi fido ciecamente di wikizionario, di repubblica, di garzanti - di nessuno. Però, wikizionario è trasparente, altri meno (sono autorevoli perchè si fanno pagare?)

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Vedi questa nostra [sezione](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/122/) che è stata costruita in modo collaborativo. Sono autorevoli perché sono stati elaborati da linguisti esperti nella materia.

Comment: Con tutto il rispetto, quella lista contiene anche fonti non troppo autorevoli. Poi, anche wikizionario è costruito in modo collaborativo (e trasparente). Poi, guarda caso, wikizionario è uno dei rari dizionari che riporta la voce, ed è giusta, e scrivere "questo termine non blablabla ..." è trasparenza in parole semplici invece di un autorevole "uso incerto / grafia incerta / etimologia incerta" che significa semplicemente "abbiamo dei dubbi". E non  dico che wikizionario sia meglio di altri, ma ne apprezzo l'impostazione, se capisci ciò che intendo.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Per discutere questo tipo di cose, penso sia meglio porre una domanda su [Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/). Puoi scriverla [in italiano](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1408/) se lo preferisci.

Answer (score 2):

Il verbo cachinnare ha origini latine, e vuol dire "ridere smoderatamente, in maniera beffarda". Per cui direi che si possa intendere come "non smettevo di ridere mentre ero intento a qualche nuovo scherzo...."

PS: Uno dei miei film preferiti! "Vivo morendo in caserma, non in tempo di guerra, ma in tempo di vita." Ha riassunto in una frase la vita di un'intera generazione! :)

Comment: Per curiosità, hai trovato registrato da qualche parte il verbo “cachinnare” in italiano?

Comment: @DaG: Finalmente si è trovato.

Comment: Ottimo, @Charo! Puoi autoaccettarti la risposta (ammesso che tu lo voglia fare)?